# Take/Obtain A Stake

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the usage of "*take a stake*" [here](http://online.wsj.com/articles/ackman-takes-stake-in-animal-health-company-zoetis-1415738359):

> Activist investor William Ackman has ***taken a roughly $2 billion stake*** in Zoetis Inc. and could push the animal-health company to sell itself to a large drug maker such as Valeant Pharmaceuticals International Inc., according to people familiar with the matter.

The "*take*" in "***taken*** *a roughly $2 billion stake*" seems to have same meaning as the "*take*" in "***take*** *a car*", which is a informal version of "*obtain a car*."  So, would substituting "***obtained*** *a roughly $2 billion stake*" the for slightly informal "***taken*** *a roughly $2 billion stake*" be better, at least in a honorable newspaper like WSJ?

Answer (score 3):

I would think the author of this used 'take' to imply a use of force or effort. Maybe not literal physical force but beat out a competitor.

Simply 'obtaining' doesn't imply this. No implication of motive or tactics used without directly expressing it. In general, it has an overall mellow tone.

I obtained the documents. (could have been given/handed directly to me.)

I obtained the documents by stealing them from the desk. (expressing the effort)

I took the documents from the desk. (not necessarily stole them but implies more force or effort.)

Answer (score 2):

It would not be better to use "obtain", because "to take a stake in" is a standard expression, especially used among specialists in business and finance.

Using  "obtain" would be ok, but there is no objective basis for deeming it better.

Comment: Just to add to my defense as a general rule and add to your claim of regular expression: I would think it requires effort and tactics to be a specialist involved in high stakes thus making it a regular expression.

Comment: Bingo to your "business and finance" slant. [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+a+stake+in%2Cobtain+a+stake+in&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows which expression is more prominent; [these hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22take%20a%20stake%20in%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1978,cd_max:2004&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) confirm your assertion about the domain where this is routine nomenclature.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with David and Jim Reynolds. "Obtain" would be perfectly valid here, but "take" is fine too. I don't see any reason to say "obtain" would be better. As David says, "take" indicates action on the part of the person getting the thing, while "obtain" is more neutral. If I beat someone up and steal his property, I have "taken" it. If he gives it to me as a present, I have "obtained" it, but I haven't "taken" it.